# I am doing project in yii 1.1 ,in $_post['submit']; I get all data but image data not get so what I have to do?

Tags: php

This is image of coding in sitecontroller.php file.

[image]

this is image of print_r[$_POST];

[image]

Comment: Hi, please post your code and error in your question in text form. Don't post images of your code and errors!

Comment: Ok next time I will..

Comment: You can use the [edit] button to make changes to your question to improve it. Posting as text makes it easier to copy/paste the code to test it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you upload image you should check in [$_FILES](http://php.net/manual/bg/reserved.variables.files.php), `print_r($_FILES);` in your case.

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    print_r($_FILES)';
}
```

Comment: Ok by print_r($_FILES); I got image data. but now  in $_Post I get other data and in $_files I get image data then now how I insert data of both in yii 1.1?

Comment: You should post another question about this, but before this check google there is a lot of information there :) Good Luck